# React переход между экранами (компонентами)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vk-mini-apps

Продолжаю изучать React, и мне стал интересен один момент.

Есть навигация по страницам через react-router-dom, тут все понятно, переход по страницам без перезагрузки страницы.

Но я наткнулся на библиотеку от В Контакте под названием VKUI, в которой имеется компонент `<Root />`, а он в свою очередь имеет коллекцию из дочерних элементов `<View />` и свойство activeView.

Суть в том, что при изменении свойства activeView, нам открывается нужный экран (View), но это работает не как ссылка, а как рендер компонента, т.е. в адресной строке путь не меняется.

Мне стало интересно, как называется такой способ реализации переходов, какие у него плюсы и минусы?

Comment: Роут красиво смотрится для пользователя и удобен для поисковых систем при индексации вашего контента на странице. Остальное можно назвать как "условный рендер", т.е. рендер по каким то событиям, ключам, флажкам. Для пользователя поведение будет одно, а вот для поисковика совсем другое. Ну и отдельно можно выделить, что при роуте, пользователь может сразу попасть на нужный раздел/компонент, встатвив правильный URL, при рендере по условию, придется прожать нужные кнопки для получения нужного компонента(т.к. будет какое то значение по умолчанию при старте).

Comment: Преимуществ никаких, зато куча недостатков. Условную отрисовку полезно использовать, но не для реализации многостраничности и навигации.